# How to create pubspec.yaml by command?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I am learning Dart (2.9.3). I use `pub global activate webdev` command.

I think it will work like `npm` in Node.js and create `pubspec.yaml` automatically, but it didn't.

Do I need to add more switches (like `--save`) to `pub global`?

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to use `dart create -t web-simple my_directory` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pub global activate webdev` command activates [webdev](https://pub.dev/packages/webdev) package to use on your computer. This package is

> A command-line tool for developing and deploying web applications with Dart.

As author wrote in [usage section](https://pub.dev/packages/webdev#usage)

> `webdev` provides two commands: `serve` and `build`.

But neither of both creates `pubspec.yaml` file.

If you want to generate a project, you can use [stagehand](https://pub.dev/packages/stagehand). But there is no option to generate customized `pubspec.yaml` file. Dart must know which packages to use in a particular project, and only this file can provide those informations.